# Segmentation fault problem, gdb message

Tags: mysql, c

I have been trying to understand why I get "SEGMENTATION FAULT" while running a program written in C languagge.

I tried gdb.

This is the message I got:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0016e5e0 in mysql_slave_send_query () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function mysql_slave_send_query, 
which has no line number information.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

The fact is that I get no compiler error/warning messages but the program doesn't work
properly.

Can anyone help me?

My query is:

```
char query[512];
    sprintf(query, "SELECT t1.Art_Acquisto as 'Cod',t2.Des_Articolo as 'Descrizione',t4.Cod_Categoria as 'Cat.',t1.Data_Acquisto as"                   "'data',t1.Netto_Acquisto as'Importo',t3.Des_Fornitore as 'Fornitore' from "
               "Aquisti as t1, Articoli as t2, Fornitori as t3, Categorie as t4  where t1.Art_Acquisto = t2.Cod_Articolo and "  
                       "t1.fornitoreM = t3.codiceF and t4.codiceC = t2.categoriaA and Art_Acquisto ='%s'order by Data_Acquisto;",Cod_Articolo);
```

Comment: First, compile and like with the `-g` flags to get debug symbols and ensure that the crash really happens with the `sprintf`. Also, ensure that `Cod_Articolo` isn't so big that it pushes the string over the 511 byte (+ null sentinel) border. Last but not least, does `Cod_Articolo` actually point to a valid memory location with a null terminated C string ?

Comment: Also of interest how you actually call `mysql_slave_send_query` (or if that is wrapped by another method, how you call that). My point is: is it possible that you've passed an uninitialized or wrong pointer ? For example, do you pass `query` or `&query` ?

Comment: Can you show us the code from the definition of Cod_Articolo to the call to `mysql_slave_send_query()`?

Answer (score 2):

Check your arguments to mysql_slave_send_query, especially the length and the proper initialisation/allocation of the other arguments.

Comment: Is it possible that your query is larger than 511 characters? In other words - how long is Cod_Articolo?

Comment: I tried to increase char[512] to char [1024] but it doesn't work..Cod_Articolo in Mysql is declared as char[20]..if only I could send my code to someone things would be easier

Comment: @Vera: Just a small note on etiquette. Asking whether you can send someone code to look at is considered impolite by many, since you're asking that someone to maybe invest more time than he already wanted (remember, we're helping you for free). It's better to update your question with all the details we asked for and paste the relevant code pieces there so that everyone can see these information and help you.

Comment: I do apologize for that ..the fact is that I do need to solve the problem...I'd like to post the entire code but here I can't do it (no space available) ..Should I open another discussion?

Answer (score 0):

"Segmentation fault" means  that your program is accessing an invalid memory location during the execution of the function named mysql_slave_send_query.
Therefore this means there is a bug in your C program.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the contents of `Cod_Articolo`? Your query is nearly 400 characters, and the buffer you're storing it in is only 512 characters - if `Cod_Articolo` is over 110 characters, your code will break.

If this is the problem, you can prevent it by checking the size of `Cod_Articolo` before writing it into the query string. Even better, you could calculate the size the query string needs to be, and allocate exactly the right amount.

It's also good practice to use [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) instead of `sprintf`, as then you can ensure you don't copy too many characters into the destination string.

Comment: thanks ..Cod_Articolo is char[20] and I also tried to increase char[512] to char [1024] but it doesn't work..

Comment: OK. Is there a null character `'\0'` at the end of Cod_Articolo?

Comment: I've just added it in the query string ....nd Art_Acquisto ='%s'\0''order by Data_Acquisto;",Cod_Articolo);...but to no avail..I also tried snprintf but I get a few errors...

Comment: What are the errors? The best way for us to help is to see more code - see my comment on your question :)

Comment: Putting the null character in the query string won't work - sprintf uses the null at the end of the string it's copying from (in this case Cod_Articolo) to find out when to stop copying. However, this may not be the problem - with more code we can help more :)

Comment: May I send the code to you?..or if you want I can leave you my email address...I know this might be frowned upon but I do need help ..

Comment: In your case your snprintf line should look like this: `snprintf(query,20,"SELECT...`

Comment: It would be best if you could post the code in your question - then others can help too.

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't work...snprintf(query, 512, "SELECT t1.Art_Acquisto as 'Cod',t2.Des_Articolo as 'Descrizione',t4.Cod_Categoria as 'Cat.',t1.Data_Acquisto as"           "'data',t1.Netto_Acquisto as'Importo',t3.Des_Fornitore as 'Fornitore' from "
         "Aquisti as t1, Articoli as t2, Fornitori as t3, Categorie as t4  where t1.Art_Acquisto = t2.Cod_Articolo and " 
                       "t1.fornitoreM = t3.codiceF and t4.codiceC = t2.categoriaA and Art_Acquisto ='%s'\0''order by Data_Acquisto;",Cod_Articolo);